# Adjust GridView to all Screen Sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, screen-size

Im trying to implement a GridView as part of a image gallery. I followed the following example from the [Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

The tutorial seems to work for all screen sizes. As you can see below the proportions for a small and a large screen size are displayed correctly (on the left - small screen size, on the right - large screen size.

[image: GridView tutorial from android developer portal]

But now to my problem. When I want to implement exactly the same GridView within a LinearLayout from my Android Project - the correct proportions are gone - as shown by the images below. The pictures begin to overlap so forth and so on.

[image: My android project]

I am quite sure that this has something to with my LinearLayout which looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/widget64"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget34"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/foto_detail_bg_cell_0"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flyer"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget36"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toptext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Beat.It"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/widget39"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="http://www.google.at"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/widget40"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/widget41"
                        android:layout_width="58dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/facebook_share"/>
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/widget42"
                        android:layout_width="58dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/photocount"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/gridview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:columnWidth="90dp"
              android:numColumns="auto_fit"
              android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
              android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
              android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
              android:gravity="center"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

**The MAIN QUESTION:**
The Layout XML used by the tutorial on the [Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) only uses the GridView alone, without a LinearLayout and and it is shown with correct proportions on each screen size. Why is that? And why does it not work properly when I nest the GridView in a Linear Layout like in my project?

Comment: I have some suggestions, you can try them out:  (1) Put GridLayout inside a FrameLayout.   (2) Don't define any gravity.   (3) Give fix number for numColumns.

Comment: And yes, don't give a columnWidth if you are using numColumns as auto_fit.

Comment: Oh my dear. Finally i got it after more than 5 hours experimenting. Thank you for your suggestions, but they didn't work. I calculated the dp values for the size of the imageView instead in my ImageAdapter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I solved this issue by editing the ImageAdapter of the GridView. I calculated the size of the generated image views - density independent.

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  

            //Calculation of ImageView Size - density independent.
            //maybe you should do this calculation not exactly in this method but put is somewhere else.
            Resources r = Resources.getSystem();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, r.getDisplayMetrics());


            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)px, (int)px));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To adjusting Gridview to screen size

In `onCreate` take rowHeight :

//Get root view

```
root = binding.root
```

// Or you can use `findviewbyid(R.id.root)`

```
view.onGlobalLayout {
            rowHeight =
                root.measuredHeight / currentPageNumberOfRow
            fillView(appsList)
        }
```

In adapter:

```
          override fun getView(position: Int, ConvertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
            var mConvertView = ConvertView
            if (layoutInflater == null) {
                layoutInflater =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as 
                        layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.item_app_shortcut, null)
          }

           if (mConvertView == null) {
                mConvertView =
                layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.item_child_launcher_app, null)
               
        //Add this: 

         mConvertView.layoutParams = AbsListView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, rowHeight)

            }
```

Dont forget set row image:

```
     android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

To fit on screen